# WordPress MysqlError: Unknown storage engine 'InnoDB'

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I got a lot MySQL error in some mysql_query in native WP functions, all of them in wp-includes/ folder.

MySQL server version is 5.5.42, and all table types are MyISAM.

```
MysqlError: Unknown storage engine 'InnoDB'
```

It is called in `wp-db.php`, `rating.php`, `plugin.php`, `admin-header.php` and `index.php`, last two files are in `wp-admin/` folder.

Comment: Run this command in mysql and share the result into the question `show variables like 'have_innodb';`

Answer (score 2):

Delete the innodb log files and try restarting your mysql services on the server. That will work ..