# wordpress database error :mysql

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I want to copy my website(= production ) to instant wordpress(= local ) with duplicator that is wordpress plugin.
Then I have this error.(I use xserver)

INSTALL ERROR!
No tables where created during step 1 of the install. Please review the installer-log.txt file for sql error messages. You may have to manually run the installer-data.sql with a tool like phpmyadmin to validate the data input. If you have enabled compatibility mode during the package creation process then the database server version your using may not be compatible with this script.

and installer-log.txt is below.

```
      DATABASE RESULTS
      --------------------------------------
     **ERROR** database error write 'Unknown storage engine 'InnoDB'' - [sql=
     CREATE TABLE `wp_commentmeta` (
     `meta_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL A...]
      **ERROR** database error write 'Unknown storage engine 'InnoDB'' - [sql=
      CREATE TABLE `wp_comments` (
      `comment_ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL A...]
      **ERROR** database error write 'Unknown storage engine 'InnoDB'' - [sql=
      CREATE TABLE `wp_duplicator_packages` (
      `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NUL...]
      **ERROR** database error write 'Unknown storage engine 'InnoDB'' - [sql=
      CREATE TABLE `wp_links` (
      `link_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_IN...]
      **ERROR** database error write 'Unknown storage engine 'InnoDB'' - [sql=
      CREATE TABLE `wp_options` (
      `option_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUT...]
      **ERROR** database error write 'Unknown storage engine 'InnoDB'' -   [sql=
      CREATE TABLE `wp_popularpostsdata` (
       `postid` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
     `da...]
     **ERROR** database error write 'Unknown storage engine 'InnoDB'' - [sql=
     CREATE TABLE `wp_popularpostssummary` (
     `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_IN...]
     **ERROR** database error write 'Unknown storage engine 'InnoDB'' - [sql=
     CREATE TABLE `wp_postmeta` (
     `meta_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO...]
     **ERROR** database error write 'Unknown storage engine 'InnoDB'' - [sql=
     CREATE TABLE `wp_posts` (
      `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREME...]
      **ERROR** database error write 'Unknown storage engine 'InnoDB'' - [sql=
     CREATE TABLE `wp_term_relationships` (
      `object_id` bigint(20) unsigned N...]
     **ERROR** database error write 'Unknown storage engine 'InnoDB'' - [sql=
      CREATE TABLE `wp_term_taxonomy` (
      `term_taxonomy_id` bigint(20) unsigned...]
      **ERROR** database error write 'Unknown storage engine 'InnoDB'' - [sql=
      CREATE TABLE `wp_termmeta` (
      `meta_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO...]
      **ERROR** database error write 'Unknown storage engine 'InnoDB'' - [sql=
      CREATE TABLE `wp_terms` (
      `term_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_IN...]
      **ERROR** database error write 'Unknown storage engine 'InnoDB'' - [sql=
      CREATE TABLE `wp_usermeta` (
       `umeta_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUT...]
       **ERROR** database error write 'Unknown storage engine 'InnoDB'' - [sql=
      CREATE TABLE `wp_users` (
      `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREME...]
      **ERROR** database error write 'Table 'wordpress.wp_comments' doesn't exist' - [sql=
```

I'm sorry that's too long.
Please help me...

Comment: can you try with normal migration method(without using duplicator plugin)?

Comment: Is it becuse duplicator may cause the error?

Comment: check following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29715727/wordpress-mysqlerror-unknown-storage-engine-innodb